# When appending 'a' to an array, does the array equate to [a] or ['a']?

Tags: python

```
array = []
array.append('a')
print array
```

The python 2.7 IDLE outputs `['a']`, but is `[a]` equal to that?

Comment: `array[0] == 'a'`. The list is `['a']`

Answer (score 3):

No `'a'` is a string while `a` is a variable name. `a` could be equal to `'a'` but that is not possible to know in your example.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what `a` is equal to since `a` is a variable.

```
a = 1
assert [a] == [1]
assert [a] != ['a']
a = 'a'
assert [a] == ['a']
```